# Deino before the E4

Tags: pokemon-black-2-white-2

Is there a way to get a deino(Hygreigon) before defeating the Elite 4?
I've looked it up but there are mixed answers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Googling "deino bw2" and following [the first link](https://www.serebii.net/pokedex-bw/633.shtml), I can tell you that Deino is not found in the wild in Pokémon BW2. However, [Zweilous](https://www.serebii.net/pokedex-bw/634.shtml) can be [found on the 7th floor of the Victory Road and at the entrance to N's castle](https://www.serebii.net/pokedex-bw/location/634.shtml). Clicking on the [Pokéarth link](https://www.serebii.net/pokearth/unova/victoryroadb2w2.shtml) then reveals that the BW2 Victory Road doesn't have 7 floors, but Zweilous can be found on the [third floor](https://www.serebii.net/pokearth/unova/victoryroadb2w2.shtml#bw-3f) and the entrance to N's castle, which is this area:

[image: Serebii's screenshot of area Zweilous can be found in]

Comment: And the Zweilous is in the grass outside the entrance, which is blocked, correct?